# Android Camera 2 API - Speed-up preview

Tags: android, performance, android-camera2

I am previewing a USB camera on TextureView on Android device.
I've observed slowness in rendering.

Scenario is - there is an object (say a bottle) where camera is focused. There are colorful lights (white, red, yellow etc.). I am capturing photos of an object by switching lights one by one. Suppose I switch on any light, then the preview takes around 2 seconds to reflect the colour change on an object.

Below is the code.

```
SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
assert texture != null;
Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
texture.setDefaultBufferSize(viewWidth,viewHeight);
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_ACTION);
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_HDR);
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE,CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG);
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get better results if you use `TEMPLATE_PREVIEW` instead of `TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the same. Can you please tell whether all other parameters which I've set are necessary or not?

Comment: I just checked TEMPLATE_PREVIEW but the results are same.

Comment: The other one you could try to change/disable is `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_HDR`.

Comment: Then the only idea I have left is trying a different device. Camera2 API implementations are notoriously buggy on many devices.

Comment: What about CameraX?

Comment: Haven't worked with it before, but CameraX is a wrapper around Camera2, so if the Camera2 implementation is buggy, then CameraX probably won't help. But if you're lucky, it might have a workaround for your specific problem, so you could give it a try.

Comment: P.S. Did you try just TEMPLATE_PREVIEW without any controls?

Comment: Without any controls means?

Comment: I.e. without any of the `captureRequestBuilder.set(...)` calls.

Comment: OK, I will try and confirm. Meanwhile, can you please check my another query here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026438/how-to-take-multiple-photos-without-preview-using-camera2-api-in-android