# How to take multiple photos without preview using Camera2 API in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I need to capture multiple photos using Camera2 API after particular interval, say 5 seconds.
I need to do it without preview. I am able to capture a single photo without preview, but I need to know how to capture multiple photos?
Once the camera is opened, I don't want to set all parameters again and again, I just want to capture photos after particular interval and once all photos are captured, then I will close the camera.

Also only first time the image is getting captured. Second time when I call takepciture() method, nothing happens.

Below is my code.

Please help.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class CameraAdmin {

    Context context;

    private static final String TAG = "CameraAdmin";

    private String mCameraId;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private String cImgType,cFileToSave;
    public boolean CaptureCompleted;
    CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder;

    public CameraAdmin(Context context,String CameraID) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mCameraId=CameraID;
        this.CaptureCompleted=false;
    }

    public void openCamera() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        setUpCameraOutputs();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void setUpCameraOutputs() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, null);

            return;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            createCameraCaptureSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

    };

    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ImageAvailable");
            final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            final ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            saveImageToDisk(bytes);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(MainActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
            intent.putExtra("dataToPass", "Image Saved!");
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            image.close();
        }
    };

    private void saveImageToDisk(final byte[] bytes)
    {
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + cFileToSave +".jpg");
        try (final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            output.write(bytes);
            Log.d("FileSaved","FileSaved");

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while saving picture to external storage ", e);
        }
    }
    public void closeCamera() {
        try {
            if (null != mCaptureSession) {
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != imageReader) {
                imageReader.close();
                imageReader = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        } finally {
        }
    }


    private void createCameraCaptureSession() {
        try {

            captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION,-3);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, 0f);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(imageReader.getSurface()),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                                return;
                            }
                            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Configuration Failed");
                        }
                    }, null
            );
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(String ImgType,String FileToSave) {
        try {
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            this.cImgType = ImgType;
            this.cFileToSave = FileToSave;
            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure a repeating request on the `CameraCaptureSession` object. Documentation for that is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#setRepeatingRequest(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler)

Comment: As i mentioned, I want to capture images one by one by 2-3 seconds interval without preview. I am planning to it through WorkManager in the background. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, have you tried the repeating request? This is what it's designed for.

Comment: In the `onConfigured` callback.

Comment: Actually I tried capturing photos with WorkManager and creating a Camera class. I want to capture these photos even if user switches between activities. What I found is that when activity is switched, it captures some garbage image.

Comment: @Vito Are you able to take multiple captures inside Workmanager? I am try to do same but not sucees till now.